# How can I get rid of invasive privacy notice popups/sticky footers in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, privacy

Lately it seems like a large majority of the websites I visit are pestered with invasive popups or sticky footer bars that take up the majority of my screen space, telling me about each website's privacy policy.

### Something like:

> We use cookies and other tracking technologies to improve your browsing experience on our site, show personalized content and targeted ads, analyze site traffic, and understand where our audience is coming from. To find out more or to opt-out, please read our Cookie Policy. In addition, please read our Privacy Policy, which has also been updated and became effective May 23rd, 2018. By choosing I Accept, you consent to our use of cookies and other tracking technologies.

There are many variations to these notices but they are all equally invasive and annoying when wanting to get to my content as they need to be clicked away constantly.

Although I appreciate the thinking behind companies having to be upfront and state exactly what they are up to with cookies etc, this serves no purpose to me.
I am already taking sufficient privacy precautions through my browser configuration and other measures that fit my preferred privacy model.

---

As such I couldn't care less to see all these annoying popups and they keep interrupting my flow. How can I get rid of them? Is there an addon or other configuration hack that can permanently get rid of these notices without breaking most websites? (like Noscript would, for instance)

Any ideas on how I could achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are going to be hard-pressed to find a single way to block these notifications since there are a million and one ways to display that notification to a user.  In most cases those notifications won't appear again, provided you have a cookie, indicating you agreed to their terms.  The websites are required to display that notification to you by the way, per the new laws, that recently went into effect in the EU.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you. The issue is that I often block or clear cookies, making these notices even more annoying as they keep reappearing even when I consent. I have no objection to the law and believe it's actually good for consumers but I just wish there was a way to opt-out from these invasive notices. Would you perhaps happen to know if these notices usually appear only to visitors connecting from the EU? I am wondering if routing all my connections outside the EU with a VPN would get rid of these notifications?

Comment: Attempting to identify a user's country of origin is both inefficient and ineffective.  I can easily hide my country of origin using a free proxy.  Whom the notice is displayed to entirely depends on the individual site.

Comment: They happen from anywhere depending on how the site is configured is my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Addon you can find via that [link](https://www.i-dont-care-about-cookies.eu/) should do what you are asking for. It's called 'I don't care about cookies'. I use it since several months now; works like a charm with some exeptions. Even in situations when it does not work, it does not make the situation worse.

From Addon description: (...) "This browser extension removes annoying cookie warnings from almost all websites and saves you thousands of unnecessary clicks!

By using it, you explicitly allow websites to do whatever they want with cookies they set on your computer (which they mostly do anyway, whether you allow them or not). (...)

Comment: Fantastic, this was just what I was looking for. Works perfectly. Thank you!